# Error accessing AWS through Visual Studio 2017

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I'm trying to connect to AWS (Amazon Web Services) using Visual Studio 2017. However, in the AWS Explorer in Visual Studio, it says "Failed to connect to AWS".

1. I created an account in the AWS IAM Management Console.
2. I assigned this account AdministratorAccess and created access keys.
3. I installed the AWS SDK for .NET for Visual Studio 2017.
4. In the Visual Studio AWS Explorer, I selected and created a New Account Profile.
5. The AWS Explorer shows "Failed to connect to AWS". (The Region list is still disabled.)

It seems like a rather simple process, but it's not working for me.

As a credential test, I set up the AWS CLI (Command Line Interface). Then I ran `aws configure` using the same Access key ID and Secret access key. I was able to access AWS--e.g. `aws iam list-users` and `aws lambda list-functions`. (I have some test lambda functions in my account already, and they showed up.)

What am I missing? Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now it's suddenly working. I hadn't touched it for a while, and then clicked 'Refresh' in the AWS Explorer. The Regions list is now populated and all of my services are displayed.

Is it possible that AWS takes a while to propagate users and access? Just a thought.

-- Update

I tried again the following day, and now I get the original error again. I have not changed anything. In fact, my dev environment was left open overnight.

What the heck could have possibly changed?

Comment: I got the same issue, it suddenly stops working this morning

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Fiddler installed and running? If yes, please close the Fiddler and try again.